# Something, something "reality cowboys"?

Tags: story-identification

Many years ago I read a series of books featuring a world where matter/reality breaks down outside of town limits. There may have been the word "cowboys" in the title of one of the books (the first?).

I remember a character with a samurai sword (possibly two?). I also remember a scene where a female leader receives cunnilingus from her entire army?

Possibly written in the nineteen seventies?

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is Mick Farren's [DNA Cowboy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/552197.The_DNA_Cowboys_Trilogy) trilogy:

- The Quest of the DNA Cowboys
- Synaptic Manhunt
- The Neural Atrocity

> Striding out of Pleasant Gap come a trio of drifters, Billy Oblivion,
>   Reave Mekonta, and The Minstrel Boy, the DNA Cowboys, reproduction
>   pistols in hand. They hit the trail through the molecular dissolution
>   of the Nothings, teetering on the edge of non-existence, to Graveyard
>   and beyond. Join them in their encounters with Brother Jeb Stuart Ho,
>   the Sex-O-Mats and Torture Parlors, Stuff Central, and A.A. Catto, the
>   sadistic child-woman ruler of Quahal.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of turning your answer into an answer. If you want to pass comments and communicate with other users, please use the [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189230/something-something-reality-cowboys/189236?noredirect=1#) system

Comment: Oh, that's much improved. Thank you so much.